# Are the 480 years of 1 Kings 6:1 wrong?

Tags: jesus, 1-kings, chronology

Here is my particular biblical chronology based on a literalist interpretation of the Bible, the only problem I have is that I cannot fit the 480 years of 1 Kings 6:1 into it:

> And it came to pass in the four hundred and eightieth year after the
> children of Israel were come out of the land of Egypt, in the fourth
> year of Solomon’s reign over Israel, in the month Zif, which is the
> second month, that he began to build the house of the Lord.

- **(925 BC)** Fifth year of Rehoboam. What is the basis for this? This date is important. The archaeological discoveries and radiocarbon dating date the invasion of Israel carried out by Pharaoh Shoshenq I in 925 BC, this allows us to identify him with Pharaoh Shishak of [1 Kings 14:25-26](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Kings%2014%3A25-26&version=KJV) and [2 Chronicles 12:1-12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Chronicles%2012%3A1-12&version=KJV), who plundered the treasures of the temple of Jerusalem in the fifth year of King Rehoboam.
- **(970–930 BC)** Kingdom of Solomon (cf. [1 Kings 11:42](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Kings%2011%3A42&version=KJV)).
- **(1010–970 BC)** Kingdom of David. The first 7 years he reigned in Hebron over Judah, the next 33 years he reigned from Jerusalem
  over all Israel and Judah (cf. [2 Samuel 5:4-5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Samuel%205%3A4-5&version=KJV); cf. [1 Kings
  2:11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Kings%202%3A11&version=KJV)).
- **(1050–1010 BC)** Kingdom of Saul (cf. [Acts 13:21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%2013%3A21&version=KJV)).
- **(1070–1050 BC)** Samuel (cf. [1 Samuel 7:2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Samuel%207%3A2&version=KJV)).
- **(1110–1070 BC)** Eli (cf. [1 Samuel 4:18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Samuel%204%3A18&version=KJV)). If we add the 410 years from the Book of Judges and the 40 years in which Eli
  judged, we get 450 exact years (cf. [Acts 13:20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%2013%3A20&version=KJV)).
- **(1520–1110 BC)** Judges. If you read the Book of Judges, you will see that the different periods in which judges judge over Israel
  and the periods in which Israel is oppressed by different foreign
  kings, add up to a total of 410 years.
- **(1550–1520 BC)** Joshua and elders. During this period Joshua dies at 110 (cf. [Joshua 24:29](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Joshua%2024%3A29&version=KJV)).
- **(1550 BC)** Conquest of Jericho. What is the basis for this? This is another important date. There is irrefutable evidence (based on
  radiocarbon dating by Hendrik J. Bruins and Johannes van der Plicht
  in 1995) that there was massive destruction of the city between 1617
  BC and 1530 BC. Kathleen Kenyon previously, in the 1950s had dated
  the destruction of the city in 1550 BC by stratigraphic dating. These
  dates are perfectly consistent with the years from Joshua to Eli as
  recounted in the Book of Judges. On this date Moses also dies at 120 (cf. [Deuteronomy 34:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy%2034%3A7&version=KJV)).
- **(1590 BC)** Date of Exodus. 40 years before the taking of Jericho (cf. [Numbers 14:33-34](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers%2014%3A33-34&version=KJV)).
- **(1670 BC)** Birth of Moses. Moses was 80 years old in the Exodus (cf. [Exodus 7:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%207%3A7&version=KJV)), so 1590 + 80 = 1670.
- **(1949 BC)** Death of Joseph at 110 (cf. [Genesis 50:22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2050%3A22&version=KJV)).
- **(1990 BC)** Beginning of the oppression of the children of Israel by the Egyptians (cf. [Genesis 15:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2015%3A13&version=KJV)).
- **(2003 BC)** Death of Jacob at 147 (cf. [Genesis 47:28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2047%3A28&version=KJV)).
- **(2020 BC)** Jacob and his sons enter Egypt to accompany his other son Joseph (cf. [Exodus 12:40](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2012%3A40&version=KJV)).
- **(2030 BC)** Death of Isaac at 180 (cf. [Genesis 35:28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+35%3A28&version=KJV)).
- **(2059 BC)** Birth of Joseph. Jacob was 91 years old. Joseph was 30 years old at the beginning of the 7 years of abundance when he
  was presented to Pharaoh (cf. [Genesis 41:46](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2041%3A46&version=KJV)). His father Jacob
  and his brothers went down to Egypt in the second of the years of
  scarcity (cf. [Genesis 45:1-13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2045%3A1-13&version=KJV)), so Joseph was already 30 + 7
  years of abundance + 2 years of scarcity = 39 years. At that same
  time Jacob was 130 years old (cf. [Genesis 47:7-9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2047%3A7-9&version=KJV)), so it is
  easy to calculate that Jacob had Joseph at 130 − 39 = 91 years old.
- **(2071 BC)** Death of Eber at 464 (cf. [Genesis 11:16-17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A16-17&version=KJV)).
- **(2100 BC)** Death of Shem at 600 (cf. [Genesis 11:10-11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A10-11&version=KJV)).
- **(2132 BC)** Death of Salah at 433 (cf. [Genesis 11:14-15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A14-15&version=KJV)).
- **(2135 BC)** Death of Abraham at 175 (cf. [Genesis 25:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2025%3A7&version=KJV)).
- **(2150 BC)** Birth of Jacob. Isaac was 60 years old (cf. [Genesis 25:26](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2025%3A26&version=KJV)).
- **(2162 BC)** Death of Arphaxad at 438 (cf. [Genesis 11:12-13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A22-23&version=KJV)).
- **(2175 BC)** Death of Terah at 205 (cf. [Genesis 11:32](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A32&version=KJV)).
- **(2209 BC)** Death of Serug at 230 (cf. [Genesis 11:22-23](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A22-23&version=KJV)).
- **(2210 BC)** Birth of Isaac.
- **(2232 BC)** Death of Reu at 239 (cf. [Genesis 11:20-21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A20-21&version=KJV)).
- **(2252 BC)** Death of Noah at 950 (cf. [Genesis 9:29](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%209%3A29&version=KJV)).
- **(2262 BC)** Death of Peleg at 239 (cf. [Genesis 11:18-19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A18-19&version=KJV)).
- **(2261 BC)** Death of Nahor at 148 (cf. [Genesis 11:24-25](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A24-25&version=KJV)).
- **(2310 BC)** Birth of Abraham. Abraham was 100 years old when Isaac was born (cf. [Genesis 21:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2021%3A5&version=KJV)).
- **(2380 BC)** Birth of Terah (cf. [Genesis 11:26](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A26&version=KJV)).
- **(2409 BC)** Birth of Nahor (cf. [Genesis 11:24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A24&version=KJV)).
- **(2439 BC)** Birth of Serug (cf. [Genesis 11:22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A22&version=KJV)).
- **(2471 BC)** Birth of Reu (cf. [Genesis 11:20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A20&version=KJV)).
- **(2501 BC)** Birth of Peleg (cf. [Genesis 11:18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A18&version=KJV)).
- **(2535 BC)** Birth of Eber (cf. [Genesis 11:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A16&version=KJV)).
- **(2565 BC)** Birth of Salah (cf. [Genesis 11:14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A14&version=KJV)).
- **(2600 BC)** Birth of Arphaxad (cf. [Genesis 11:12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A12&version=KJV)).
- **(2602 BC)** Great Flood (cf. [Genesis 11:10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A10&version=KJV)). On this date Methuselah also dies at 969 (cf. [Genesis 5:27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A27&version=KJV)).
- **(2607 BC)** Death of Lamech at 777 (cf. [Genesis 5:31](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A31&version=KJV)).
- **(2700 BC)** Birth of Shem (cf. [Genesis 11:10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2011%3A10&version=KJV)).
- **(2836 BC)** Death of Jared at 962 (cf. [Genesis 5:20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A20&version=KJV)).
- **(2968 BC)** Death of Mahalaleel at 895 (cf. [Genesis 5:17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A17&version=KJV)).
- **(3023 BC)** Death of Cainan at 910 (cf. [Genesis 5:14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A14&version=KJV)).
- **(3118 BC)** Death of Enos at 905 (cf. [Genesis 5:11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A11&version=KJV)).
- **(3202 BC)** Birth of Noah. Noah was 600 years old when the Flood occurred (cf. [Genesis 7:11-12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%207%3A11-12&version=KJV)).
- **(3216 BC)** Death of Seth at 912 (cf. [Genesis 5:8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A8&version=KJV)).
- **(3271 BC)** Rapture of Enoch at 365 (cf. [Genesis 5:23-24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A23-24&version=KJV)).
- **(3328 BC)** Death of Adam at 930 (cf. [Genesis 5:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A5&version=KJV)).
- **(3384  BC)** Birth of Lamech (cf. [Genesis 5:28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A28&version=KJV)).
- **(3571 BC)** Birth  of Methuselah (cf. [Genesis 5:25](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A25&version=KJV)).
- **(3636 BC)** Birth of Enoch (cf. [Genesis 5:21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A21&version=KJV)).
- **(3798 BC)** Birth of Jared (cf. [Genesis 5:18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A18&version=KJV)).
- **(3863 BC)** Birth of Mahalaleel (cf. [Genesis 5:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A15&version=KJV)).
- **(3933 BC)** Birth of Cainan (cf. [Genesis 5:12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A12&version=KJV)).
- **(4023 BC)** Birth of Enos (cf. [Genesis 5:9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A9&version=KJV)).
- **(4128 BC)** Birth of Seth (cf. [Genesis 5:6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A6&version=KJV)).
- **(4258 BC)** Creation of Adam (cf. [Genesis 5:1-3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A1-3&version=KJV)).

Comment: Is this the Chronology of Bishop Ussher?  Have a look at some other Chronologies that are more modern such as that published by Zondervan.

Comment: This is my own chrnology based in a literalist interpretation of the dates given in the Bible. As I said, the only date that I can't fit in it are the 480 years of 1 Kings 6:1.

Comment: You should consult some others who also claim to have constructed such a literalist chronology such as the Zondervan.

Comment: Thanks, I've been searching for Zondervan chronology but If can't find nothing without paying. Can you share any Zondervan's dates that he gives in his chronology?

Comment: This is close but has errors, Joshua wasn't said to be 85, Caleb was; and also assumes that either Joshua/Caleb died and then was followed immediately by 450 years of judges/oppressions(see Jdg 2:7). Also it doesn't account for two variations of the forty years in the wilderness, one from Kadesh-barnea, the other from Egypt, nor gives the basis of the 968 BC number upon which all of it is based(very important[e.g. Ezra/Neh]). Further, the 480 year requirement may be deduced as a semantic calculation of a free Israel(with certain assumptions[e.g. 20 years the ark in house of Abinadab, etc]).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are right, I assumed that Joshua was 40 years old when Moses sent them to spy out the land and the passage in Joshua 14:10 did not refer to him but to Caleb, even so they would not change the dates. The dates of the reigns of Solomon, David, Saul, etc. counting backwards I take them from another important archaeological landmark: the archaeological discoveries and radiocarbon dating that date the invasion of Israel carried out by Pharaoh Shoshenq I in 925 BC.

Comment: Also, I am not sure one could start Adam's age from creation. He was initially made to live forever, only sin ages us. It is my view that Adam's aging process started from the time he sinned and lost access to the fruit of tree of life!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As the Bible says Adam unfortunately sinned and was subjected to the rule of death. In [Genesis 5:1-3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205%3A1-3&version=KJV) the Bible tells us that he died at the age of 930. All I do is to calculate the dates around two irrefutable archaeological discoveries: the sacking of the temple of Jerusalem by Shoshenq I in 925 BC and the destruction of Jericho in 1550 BC.

Comment: @APoL0 welcome to the site! I added the text of 1 Kings 6:1 to your post, for reference.

Comment: The Septuagint has 440 years instead of 480. The 450 years mentioned in Judges and Acts-Epistles are not necessarily consecutive, inasmuch as the judges of the various cities were like mayors with military and judicial functions, ruling in parallel with one another, and not as succeeding kings of a unified state or country.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation of the 480 years by Sir Robert Anderson (1841-1918).  It is from his book The Coming Prince: The Marvelous Prophecy of Daniel's Seventy Weeks Concerning the Antichrist, 2012 by Trumpet Press, 12/5/2013 Kindle Edition, Chapter 7, pages 85-86 (footnotes omitted)

“According to the book of Kings, Solomon began to build the temple in the 480th year after the children of Israel were come out of the land of Egypt. (1 Kings 6:1) This statement, than which none could, seemingly, be more exact, has sorely puzzled chronologers. By some it has been condemned as a forgery, by others it has been dismissed as a blunder; but all have agreed in rejecting it. Moreover, Scripture itself appears to clash with it. In his sermon at Pisidian Antioch (Acts 13:18-21) St. Paul epitomizes thus the chronology of this period of the history of his nation: forty years in the wilderness; 450 years under the judges, and forty years of the reign of Saul; making a total of 530 years. To which must be added the forty years of David’s reign and the first three years of Solomon’s; making 573 years for the very period which is described in Kings as 480 years. Can these conclusions, apparently so inconsistent, be reconciled?

“If we follow the history of Israel as detailed in the book of Judges, we shall find that for five several periods their national existence as Jehovah’s people was in abeyance. In punishment for their idolatry, God gave them up again and again, and “sold them into the hands of their enemies.” They became slaves to the king of Mesopotamia for eight years, to the king of Moab for eighteen years, to the king of Canaan for twenty years, to the Midianites for seven years, and finally to the Philistines for forty years. [4] But the sum of 8 +18+ 20+ 7+ 40 years is 93 years, and if 93 years be deducted from 573 years, the result is 480 years. It is obvious, therefore, that the 480 years of the book of Kings from the Exodus to the temple is a mystic era formed by eliminating every period during which the people were cast off by God. [5] If, then, this principle were intelligible to the Jew in regard to history, it was both natural and legitimate to introduce it in respect of an essentially mystic era like that of the seventy weeks.”